# How to use perl to filter XML file with tags?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a big XML file (2 GB) and that file contains too many useless data that need to be filtered, below is the rough structure of the XML file:

(All the useless data are replaced by "useless_information" to make it looks clean and tidy)

```
<hmdb>
    <metabolite>
        <useless_information></useless_information>
        <useless_information></useless_information>
        <useless_information></useless_information>
        <useless_information></useless_information>
        ...
        <normal_concentrations>
            <useless_information></useless_information>
            <useless_information></useless_information>
            <useless_information></useless_information>
            ...
            <concentration>
                <useless_information></useless_information>
                <useless_information></useless_information>
                <useless_information></useless_information>
                <useless_information></useless_information>
                ...
                <concentration_value> 100 </concentration_value>
                <subject_age> 21 </subject_age>
                <subject_sex> male </subject_sex>
            </concentration>
            <concentration></concentration>
            <concentration></concentration>
            <concentration></concentration>
            ...
        </normal_concentrations>
    </metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    ...
</hmdb>
```

So, basically I would like to keep the following tags and values: concentration_value, subject_age and subject_sex, the rest are all not important and can be filtered, the XML should look like this after filter it:

```
<hmdb>
    <metabolite>
        <concentration>
            <concentration_value> 100 </concentration_value>
            <subject_age> 21 </subject_age>
            <subject_sex> male </subject_sex>
        </concentration>
        <concentration></concentration>
        <concentration></concentration>
        <concentration></concentration>
        ...
    </metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    <metabolite></metabolite>
    ...
</hmdb>
```

I need the data in this file to continue my study (This file is too big, my laptop cannot open this file, so I have to filter out the useless data to decrease the size of the XML file before I use it), but I don't know how to write perl script, I'm really appreciate your help, thank you so much :)

Comment: How do you decide to keep `<normal_concentrations>` node?  By the stated criteria and shown data shouldn't the `<concentration>` node suffice?

Comment: It's nice how you condensed the sample file but I expect that there are _all_kinds of many many names of nodes to skip, which you don't know.  Do you know the names of all nodes you wish to keep? (Or is it really simply `<normal_concentrations>` and that's it?)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response, yes, I need to keep the normal_concentrations tag, and in this tag, there has 3 more tags and values need to keep, "concentration_value, subject_age and subject_sex", the rest can all be removed, but there has many "concentration" tags in each "metabolite" tags, I need to keep all of the "concentration" tags in different "metabolite" tags.

Comment: OK.  But when you say "_need to keep all of the "concentration" tags in different "metabolite" tags_" then don't you need to keep `metabolite` nodes as well? (As a structure, even if all subnodes other than `concentration` are removed.)  The desired outcome doesn't show it.

Comment: oh, yes! you are right, really appreciate it ! I need to keep the metabolite tags also, sorry for confuse you, I edit the question now :)

Comment: OK.  Next question -- can any of these nodes (say one `metabolite` node) be too big to keep in memory?  There are ways to read XML in small chunks but it helps processing if one can read a subtree (so `metabolite` node and everything below it) ... but can that be too big?

Comment: Thanks for update, it triggers another question: so do you keep `metabolite` nodes even if there's no `concentration` nodes inside them?  (That's how it looks from the eidt.)

Comment: for the memory question, I have to filter out the xml file first and test on my computer, if it is still not able to run, maybe I have to separate it into different small xml files

Comment: for the second question, if possible, all the tags without values should be removed, it can reduce the size of the xml file. thank you so much :)

Comment: You could pass the file through grep filter `egrep -v useless_information [filename]  > [newfile]`. With provided structure of the file you will be removing `useless_information` lines from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the sample of your data you have is representative (that is, all the matching tags for useless_information are on the same line) and assuming your input data is in a file called input-data.xml, the following one line perl program should work. I tested it with your sample. So at the bash (or for windows, cmd.exe) command line type this

```
perl -nle 'while(<stdin>){if(!/useless_information/){chop; print}}' <input-data.xml >output-data.xml
```

This little one line program will ignore any line that contains "useless_information" and assumes that matching tag for is always on the same line.

However, since I suspect that there may be several useless tags you want to ignore, it might be more effective to filter for what you want instead of what you don't want.

```
perl -nle 'while(<stdin>){if(/metobolite|normal_concentrations|concentration_value|subject_age|subject_sex|concentration/){chop; print}}' <input-data.xml >output-data.xml
```

This also assumes that you have perl installed and it (the executable for perl) is in your environment variable called "PATH".

Now if you find out that sometimes it (the matching tag) is not on the same line, then we will have to get a little fancier.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for the response, here's the new update, I modified your code a bit and achieve the expected result! Thank you so much! but I realized there has a lot of "<concentration>" tags without any value, may I know how to remove those empty “<concentration>” tags?? once again, thank you so much for the help!!! :)

Comment: Would it be helpful to be able to eliminate only those concentration tags that have their mates ("</concentration>") on the same line? If so, that is easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

> file contains too many useless data that need to be filtered

http://p3rl.org/xml_grep